# Display Woocommerce Categories on page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, twentytwenty

Im using woocommerce but Im not building an ecommerce site, its a site that will have a series of marketing images, starting with categories and then working towards a product.

So I have a page for instance called 'Wood Stoves', I have made that a main category and this is a page, but then inside that page I need the 'Brands' that will be associated with this category, but they still categories, so for instance 'Brand 1' its parent is 'Wood Stoves' and again it needs to have an image. So these then become clickable categories.

Then inside that brand there will be products, but I only again want an image to show with a bit of text.

So the first page is the categories (brnads) within the main category, and then inside there is the products within the brand.

My site is https://www.accend4web.co.uk/little-stove-company/ and am using the TwentyTwenty theme, which also doesnt seem to work that well with woocommerce.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual:** 
If you are not planning to fully use Woocommerce, then you can just edit the home page and add the categories one by one as images linked to the category page with you can get from the categories page under "Products" (go to the  https://www.accend4web.co.uk//wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product , then click on "View" on the category, that will send you to a page that contains all products with that category.

Then do the same for every category you have, you will get a home page with categories titles with pictures linked to the categories pages.

**Automated:** 
Insted of using the category as Brands there are some nice plugins that add the "Brands" features to  Woocommerce, and they even add the brand under the product short description and they will be linked to the brands' page which contains the product of that brand
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-brands-add-on/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/premmerce-woocommerce-brands/